# Will 'this' reference escape from Constructor in this case?

Tags: java

I understand that 'this' reference should not be escaped in Constructor due to thread safety concern, where the object is not yet completely constructed but 'leaked' out to other objects. For instance

```
public class TestClass{
       public TestClass(){
            StaticClass.addListener(this);
       }
}
```

If I invoke the default constructor in another constructor, does that guarantee the integrity of the constructed object and avoid any 'this' reference escape issues?

```
public class TestClass{
       public TestClass(){

       }
       public TestClass(String str){
            this();
            StaticClass.addListener(this);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, yes, your `this` reference is still leaked before construction is complete, and thus before the new Java 5 memory model's memory boundary for construction is reached.  You need to add the listener after your new statement, and not from anywhere in the construction sequence:

```
TestClass obj=new TestClass();
StaticClass.addListener(obj);
```

or

```
StaticClass.addListener(new TestClass());
```

Comment: I see, so as long as the current constructor (embeds default constructor or not) does not return, the object is not completely created?